# The ChromeDriver Could not be found - Selenium side runner

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, selenium-side-runner

I'm about to run test suite parallel in Selenium IDE, so I have done the configuration (guided [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner)) successfully.

Below is my selenium-side-runner folder.

[image]

My .side file is in "C:\Users\Sanjai\Downloads\OregonZoo.side".

When I run the cmd "**selenium-side-runner C:\Users\Sanjai\Downloads\OregonZoo.side**" it shows the error below:

[image]

Comment: Did you put the chromedriver in your environment variables under path.

Comment: Thank you @arundeepchohan, chromeDriver path is added and the same is working fine.